# In JavaFX2.2, how to set the font size for text entered in input fields and table headers?

Tags: javafx-2

In my JavaFX2.2 fxml program, I am finding that fonts do not scale properly. As a result, table headers and input data fields are disproportionately large.

Is there any way to set the font size for text **entered** in the input fields?

Is there any way to set the font size for text displayed in the table headers?

[image: screenshot of javafx program]

**SCCE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?> 
<?import javafx.collections.*?> 
<?import fxmltableview.*?> 
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.Person?>

<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >

    <GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="10" right="10" bottom="10" left="10"/>
        </padding>
        <Label  text="Address Book: This text is in font size 12 on Win7" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <font>
                <Font size="12.0"/>
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField fx:id="textField" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            input text field. See how large I am!!!
        </TextField>
        <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="First Name">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Last Name">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Email Address">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="email" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns> 
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <Person firstName="Jacob" lastName="Smith"  
                            email="jacob.smith@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Isabella" lastName="Johnson" 
                            email="isabella.johnson@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Ethan" lastName="Williams" 
                            email="ethan.williams@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Emma" lastName="Jones"
                            email="emma.jones@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Michael" lastName="Brown" 
                            email="michael.brown@example.com"/>
                </FXCollections>
            </items> 
        </TableView>
    </GridPane>
</Scene>

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fxmltableview;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
   private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty("");

public Person() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getPrimary() {
        return getEmail();
    }

    public String getSecondary() {
        return getEmail();
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }
}

public class FXMLTableViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}

package fxmltableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class FXMLTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       primaryStage.setTitle("FXML TableView Example");
       primaryStage.setScene
       ((Scene)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_tableview.fxml")));
       primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can override the `-fx-font-size` of the corresponding controls in a CSS file.

Comment: Could you proviced an sscce.

Comment: This is not really a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example

Comment: @gontard you are correct, and I apologize. I have added the SCCE.

Comment: @assylias thanks for the tip - it helped solve the problem!

Comment: @likejiujitsu glad it helped - sorry I did not have time to help more than by posting a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found these useful articles by [Marco](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part4/) and by [Rob](http://rterp.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/using-a-custom-tablecell-factory-to-format-a-javafx-table-in-fxml/)

So I

1) manually changed the width of the table column

```
        <TableColumn text="First Name" prefWidth="90" >
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Last Name" prefWidth="90" >
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
```

2) Added a link in the fxml file

```
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@tffontsize.css" />
  </stylesheets>
```

3) created a css file tfffontsize.css

```
.text-field {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
}
.table-view .column-header{
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

.table-cell {
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: instead of giving absolute sizes, you could use relative numbers `1.2em` for larger fonts or `0.8em` for smaller ones for example. So if you change the default font, it will adjust accordingly.