# JavaFX TextArea font size - weird behavior

Tags: java, textarea, javafx-8

Font size is controlled by the Combobox component:

```
fontSize.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Double> observable, Double oldValue, Double newValue) -> {
    contentField.setFont(Font.font(contentField.getFont().getFamily(), newValue));
});
```

However when I focus the textarea, this happens: (notice the megascrollbar)

[image]

This is 1:1 scale!!!

*Compiled with Java SE 1.8_45*

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926024/in-javafx2-2-how-to-set-the-font-size-for-text-entered-in-input-fields-and-tabl

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I assume you are running under 1.8.0u45 as well as compiling with it. Do you have a custom style sheet attached?

Comment: Yes I do. The text color is also applied to the textarea via `setStyle()` method, altough removing it does not solve the issue.