# How to set font for label in JavaFx from root folder?

Tags: javafx, fonts

I have stored fonts for my project  at `*>root*` directory inside `*>font*` directory.

I've tried using following code:

```
public class NewController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private Label titleLabel;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            titleLabel.setFont(Font.loadFont("fonts/Archivo-Regular.ttf", 30));
        }
    }
```

But it can not set font.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the font to the scene as Stylesheet

## Your Class

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/font.css").toExternalForm());
```

**CSS File**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Archivo';
    src: url('font/Archivo-Regular.ttf');
}
```

After that you can easily add the font to the elements in the CSS

```
.label {
 -fx-font-family: 'Archivo';
}
```

Or you can load the font in the Class. But load the font before using the style.

**Class**

```
Font.loadFont(NewController.class.getResource("Archivo-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm(), 30);
```

### Edit

**@FXML**

Here is a little Example from this [site](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/setting-affinetransform-and-font-in-fxml-vs-javafx/).

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        text.setText("My Text!");
        text.setFill(Color.RED);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 24));
    }
```

Comment: So there's no way to set using `FXML`?

Comment: @Swapnil I edited the post. What I think your main problem is the path to the resources.

Comment: I don't use `scene` cause I'm not a designer I want to make use of IDE generated classes such as `NewController.java` and `NewController.fxml` that's why I found it's difficult to achieve.

Comment: I've load a font in `Controller.java` using `Font.loadFont(NewController.class.getResource("Archivo-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm(), 30);`

Comment: @Swapnil first you need to change ```NewController.class``` to your class name. Second, what happend after loading it?

Comment: I also found a solution where you can add the .css file in the FXML and than set the font in the .css file. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233118/9892631)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199888/discussion-between-swapnil-and-poisn).